# Helping using FirePHP to debug a .php application

Tags: php, firephp, qcodo

just set up FirePHP and using a framework called Qcodo / Qcubed.  Has anyone heard of these on SO?

Been having challenges debugging -- trying to do a fairly simple new() and save() and then output via Ajax but not getting any kind of responsiveness from errors.

Any help for us, two of us have checked it out but can't seem to get a response.

Thanks!

BTW, here's the class which seems to be creating the problems:

http://github.com/allyforce/AF-upload/blob/master/Library/Target1.class.php

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you expecting a message through firePHP and not getting one?

Comment: Yes -- do I need to do something like install or instrument the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure you're using FireFox with FireBug installed. FirePHP does not work with any other combination.
Also, FireFox is the only browser that correctly displays Ajax errors.

Just to clarify, you must have http://www.firephp.org/ installed on your server for this to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to check the installation instructions, try reinstalling everything from scratch.

If that doesn't work, then consider asking a question in the Firephp [community](http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Support/Community.htm).

With FirePHP you can also get error messages (E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING) posted from PHP directly into the FirePHP Firefox extension... for details look [here](http://arbit.pl/2008/09/12/core-php-errors-support-in-firephp/)